# Kmeans cluster evaluation

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I am little bit confused with SSB calculation in Cluster evaluation
 [image]

Where

```
|Ci| is the size of cluster i
ci is the centroid of cluster i
c is the centroid of the overall data
```

What is this "centroid of the overall data"?
Everywhere it is mentioned as centroid of overall data.

Is it the intial centroid that we take for calculation?

**EDIT**

Little more clarification from anony-Mousse's answer.

Lets say we have done 1 iteration in clustering.

```
step 1: k =2, select random centroids(Let my random centroids be (2,1,3) and (3,1,1))
step 2: do clustering(Now 2 clusters are formed)
step 3: then find new centroids(by averaging data for each cluster, After averaging let my new clusters be (2.3,1.5,3) and (6.7,1,2))
```

so now I need to calculate SSB.

Now I need to calculate centroid for whole data(input data) let that value be (25,30.5,78)

```
total no of values in c1 = 20
total no of values in c2 = 30

ssbc1 = 20*(dist([2.3,1.5,3],[25,30.5,78]))^2
ssbc1 = 30*(dist([6.7,1,2],[25,30.5,78]))^2
total ssb = ssbc1+ssbc2
```

Is it like this?

Answer (score 0):

The centroid is the average in each dimension.

"Of all data" says that the clustering is *not* used.